# Is there a better way to instantiate these simple pydantic models?

Tags: pydantic

I've got a fairly large system configuration file, which I'm trying to chunk up into small pieces and represent with `pydantic` models. The idea is to get the models defined such that they reflect the structure of the config, then be able to toss a config at a top-level `Model.parse_obj` and get all the benefit of validation, defaults, etc.

**Here are a couple example models:**

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str

class House(BaseModel):
    habitants: List[Person]
```

So a config to define a house with people living in it, to work through `House.parse_obj`, would need to look like the following:

```json
{
   "habitants": [
      {"name": "homer"},
      {"name": "marge"},
      {"name": "bart"},
      {"name": "lisa"},
      {"name": "maggie"},
   ]
}
```

That works, but it is too cumbersome considering how simple the `Person` model is. It would feel more natural to do this:

```json
{
   "habitants": ["homer", "marge", "bart", "lisa", "maggie"]
}
```

This of course doesn't work, because those individual names need to be wrapped in a dict as a keyword arg.

Is there a good way to set this up, that would support using that latter style of config?

Comment: @taakov out of curiosity why did you edit the code example to use `from typing import List`, isn't the plain `list` the way to do it these days?